# Code doesn't serve my static html files in the publlic folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

Exploring express framework. Learning the express.static middleware but it doesn't function the way I expect it to.

### Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    express.static('public');
    next();
}); 

app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log("Starting first middleware");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The above code doesn't serve my static html files in the publlic folder. The public folder is on the same directory as this JS file, and when I for instance use the URL http://localhost:3000/home.html to try to access the home.html file in the public folder I cannot access it.

When I switch up the order that the express.static is last it does serve my static html file in the public folder.

### Code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Starting first middleware");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

### Question:

Why doesn't my app in the first code example serve the static files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) is a function that returns another function (middleware), and Express middlewares expect 2 or 3 parameters (req, res[, next]).

When it is used as a callback, like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

you don't need to explicitly provide parameters to it, since `app.use` will provide them for you.

However, when you use it yourself, you need to explicitly call the function with its parameters:

```
app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    express.static('public')(req, res, next);
    next();
});
```

In your first example, you were generating the middleware, but not executing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundemental difference between the two snippets. You see the first one you are basically calling the function express.static with argument 'public' inside the callback function of a middleware you declared, this only will return a function that will not be used in next middlewares as no arguments passed to it; the req object should be passed to it. However in the second one this will return a function that can use the req object which is passed along with the res normally in the app.use. Take a look at some of the source code of the 'static' function to get an idea :

```
 function serveStatic (root, options) {
  if (!root) {
    throw new TypeError('root path required')
  }

  if (typeof root !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('root path must be a string')
  }

  // copy options object
  var opts = Object.create(options || null)

  // fall-though
  var fallthrough = opts.fallthrough !== false

  // default redirect
  var redirect = opts.redirect !== false

  // headers listener
  var setHeaders = opts.setHeaders

  if (setHeaders && typeof setHeaders !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('option setHeaders must be function')
  }

  // setup options for send
  opts.maxage = opts.maxage || opts.maxAge || 0
  opts.root = resolve(root)

  // construct directory listener
  var onDirectory = redirect
    ? createRedirectDirectoryListener()
    : createNotFoundDirectoryListener()

  return function serveStatic (req, res, next) { // the funciton returned
    if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'HEAD') {
      if (fallthrough) {
        return next()
      }

      // method not allowed
      res.statusCode = 405
      res.setHeader('Allow', 'GET, HEAD')
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', '0')
      res.end()
      return
    }

    var forwardError = !fallthrough
    var originalUrl = parseUrl.original(req)
    var path = parseUrl(req).pathname

    // make sure redirect occurs at mount
    if (path === '/' && originalUrl.pathname.substr(-1) !== '/') {
      path = ''
    }

    // create send stream
    var stream = send(req, path, opts)
    //rest of code...
```